# PHP loop through current directory files for image resize

Tags: php, image, resize, directory

I have a function to resize images, which requires their names. Now what I want to do is simply place a script in a directory, run it once, and it should run that function on all those images.

In another post I found some information about [DirectoryIterator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php), but you can't have the directory empty to resemble the current folder. How do I do this?

Following code works for a specified folder (thus not current folder)

```
<?php
function Resize_Image($save,$file,$t_w,$t_h,$s_path,$o_path){
    $s_path = trim($s_path);
    $o_path = trim($o_path);
    $save = $s_path . $save;
    $file = $o_path . $file;
    $attrib = getimagesize($file);
    $width = $attrib[0];
    $height = $attrib[1];
    if(($width>$t_w) || ($height>$t_h)){
        $r1 = $t_w/$width;
        $r2 = $t_h/$height;
        if($r1<$r2){
            $size = $t_w/$width;
        }else{
            $size = $t_h/$height;
        }
    }else{ 
        $size=1; 
    }
    $modwidth = $width * $size;
    $modheight = $height * $size;
    $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight);
    switch($attrib['mime']){
        case "image/gif":
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case "image/jpeg":
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case "image/png":
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        break;
    }
    imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100);
    return; 
}

$dir = new DirectoryIterator("files/");
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $fullname = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        Resize_Image($fullname,$fullname,1366,767,'files/','files/');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to solve this.

1. You can use one of PHP's "Magic Constants," `__PATH__` to show the path to that current file. However, ot all PHP installs have this built in.
2. The function `getcwd()` returns the current directory you're looking at, which may not be where your file lives. You can try this:

   ```
    <?php
    chdir( dirname( __FILE__ ) );
    echo getcwd();
    ?>
   ```

Once you pull the directory, you can feed it into your script as it is. Hope this helps.

Comment: the `__PATH__` is not supported, but the second method does work. However when I try to run any script on my server, I get a 500 Internal Server Error, so I guess I set something up wrong...

Comment: Since the server errors on the live site, I decided to use FTP and do it locally, my local server also doesn't time out that fast so I don't need a workaround for the tons of images. Thanks!